# Azure function v3 in .NET 5 - ServiceBus trigger doesn't fire after x amount of time

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've seen a lot of similar issues, but I have no clue why this happens with my function.

In short:

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

```
[Function("EmailNotification")]
        public async Task Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("EmailNotification", Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus")]
            EmailNotification request)
```

In azure, the settings are correctly set under Configuration:

[image]

The function is being deployed by azure devops:

```
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
       displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
       inputs:
             azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
             appType: functionApp
             appName: 'notifications-test'
             package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

After a deploy or restart or a visit on the azure portal, the trigger works. So it's not an access issue I suppose.

The function runs under a **Consumption plan**.

One thing that I've noticed, in the linked storage account I can see a container called 'azure-webjobs-hosts', which contains a directory called 'synctriggers', which contains directories with the name of functions, but that folder is not present for this function.

I've called the synctriggers API endpoint already, which returns "success", but it doesn't change anything.

So after some idle time, the function is not triggered anymore. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: By moving this function to an app service plan and using "always on", everything works fine (but this doesn't solve the consumption plan issue).

Comment: Sorry for the wrong solution... Could you please check the logs first? `https://dorisservicebus.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` ->`LogFiles`